# APNS: First push delivers only

Tags: ios, push, apple-push-notifications

I've a really strange behavior in my app.
Only the first push notification send will be delivered.
All other won't arrive. I waited for 1 week, and still it wasn't delivery.
But if I reinstall the app, the first notification will be delivered instantaneously.

I never had this problem before. All other apps are working with APNS.

Thanks,

Maik

EDIT:

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'token';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'pw';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'message';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

(i tested development and production push)

Comment: Can you please share the code here which you are using to send push notifications ?

Comment: fixed it, created a new app id. Think the problem was, that i deleted the appId from the old account and created it on the new developer account.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer and close the question for further reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it, created a new app id. Think the problem was, that i deleted the appId from the old account and created it on the new developer account.